# Similarities between two vectors

Tags: list-manipulation, boolean-computation

Is there simpler and/or faster code for this?

```
List1={1,2,4,6,7};
List2={1,3,5,6,7};
```

Rule:
If values at respective positions match, output 1 else output 0.

Result:

> {1,0,0,1,1}

Answer (score 10):

```
ClearAll[f]
f = 1 - Unitize[# - #2] &;


f[List1, List2]
```

> ```
> {1, 0, 0, 1, 1}
> ```

Comment: @Reda.Kebbaj, using NonDairyNeutrino's test input it is about 20x faster than `1-Boole[Negative[-Abs[List1 -List2]]]`. Have not tested it against `ResourceFunction["BoolEval"]` (somehow I cannot download it on my machine).

Answer (score 7):

Not very efficient, but perhaps 'simpler':

```
KroneckerDelta@@@Transpose[{List1,List2}]

(* {1, 0, 0, 1, 1} *)
```

Or

```
MapThread[KroneckerDelta,{List1,List2}]

(* {1, 0, 0, 1, 1} *)
```

Answer (score 6):

Another approach:

```
list1 = {1, 2, 4, 6, 7};
list2 = {1, 3, 5, 6, 7};
1 - Mod[Sign[list2 - list1], 2]

{1, 0, 0, 1, 1}
```

Comment: I believe you wanted to write `Mod[Sign[list2 - list1 - 1], 2]`?

Comment: @Syed -- I moved the "1" around incorrectly... sorry about that

Answer (score 6):

```
List1 = {1, 2, 4, 6, 7};
List2 = {1, 3, 5, 6, 7};
Boole@*SameQ @@@ Transpose[{List1, List2}]
```

> {1, 0, 0, 1, 1}

Answer (score 5):

Maybe [`something`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/BoolEval/) from one of our own

```
list[1] = RandomReal[{0,1},10^6];
list[2] = list[1] + SparseArray[{i_?EvenQ} :> RandomReal[{0,1}], 10^6];

ResourceFunction["BoolEval"][list[1] == list[2]] // Log10@*First@*RepeatedTiming
```

> -8.07827

Comment: I second BoolEval, it is a very useful and fast toolkit.

Answer (score 4):

I code this, but I need more speed.

```
List1={1,2,4,6,7};List2={1,3,5,6,7}; 
1-Boole[Negative[-Abs[List1 -List2]]]
```